# ImageMagickで、画像にフォントの大きさが異なる2つのテキストを追加したい

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagickで、正方形画像にフォントの大きさが異なる2つのテキストを追加するには？

┌─────────────┐
│
│  1行目。ここのフォントは大きく
│
│ 2行目。ここのフォントは小さく
│
└─────────────┘

現状コード

```
convert originImg.jpg -font hogeFont.otf -pointsize 36 \
          -size 320px caption:'1行目テキスト.' output.jpg
```

Comment: こんな記事 [Imagemagick Text Placement on Images with Varying Dimensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/586192), [画像の結合１（重ね合わせ）](https://imagemagick.biz/archives/672) を参考に、それぞれのテキストだけの画像を作って、元の画像と合成するのが簡単では？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テキストの位置や色は適当に変更して下さい。

```bash
convert originImg.jpg -font hogeFont.otf -fill cyan \
  -pointsize 36 -annotate +50+50 '1行目テキスト.' \
  -pointsize 18 -annotate +50+80 '2行目テキスト.' output.jpg
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 期待通り動作しました