# ImageMagickで、「フォントの大きさが異なる」かつ「改行コードを使用せず指定横幅で自動改行」する2つのテキストを画像に追加したい

Tags: imagemagick

やりたいこと
ImageMagickで、2つのテキストを画像に追加したい。

テキスト要件
・フォントの大きさは異なる。 1番目テキストの方が２番目テキストよりフォントを大きくしたい。
・画像横幅は固定(例えば800px)
・改行コードを使用せず指定横幅(例えば500px)で自動改行したい

┌───────────────────────┐
│
│
│
│ 1番目テキスト。ここのフ
│ ォントは大きく
│
│ 2番目テキスト。ここのフ
│ ォントは小さく
│
│
│
└───────────────────────┘

現在の理解
・改行コードを使用せず指定横幅で自動改行するには、captionオプションを使用すればよい
・「フォントの大きさが異なる」2つのテキストを画像に追加するには、annotateオプションを使用すればよい

試してみたがうまくいかなかったので、GPT-3.5へ質問してみた回答の抜粋

> ImageMagickの convert コマンドにおいて、-annotate オプションと -caption
> オプションを同時に使用することはできません

２番目テキストだけでも自動改行したいと思い試したが、意図した通り動作しないコード

```
convert originImg.jpg -font hogeFont.otf -background none \
 -size 500x -pointsize 50 -fill white -gravity center -annotate +0-50 "1番目テキスト" \
 -pointsize 30 -fill blue -gravity center -annotate +0+50 size 500px  caption:"2番目テキスト。とても長いテキストです。" \
 -gravity center output.jpg
```

Q.やりたいことをするためにはどうすればよいですか？
1番目テキストと２番目テキストの両方を、改行コードを使用せず指定横幅で自動改行したいのですが、難しければ２番目テキストだけでも自動改行したい

Comment: 「2つのテキストを」は [別質問で解決済み](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/96245) ではないのですか？あえてまた繰り返す意図がわかりません。(十分簡略化できるはずです) / "改行せずに自動改行" も表現が矛盾しており分かりづらいです。一般的には「折り返し」と表現します。

Comment: 1回で両方やろうとせずに2回に分けて行うとか、前の質問にコメントしたように文字も単独で別々の画像にして3つを合成するとか？ [【ImageMagick】文字を画像にする](https://blog.narumium.net/2018/11/12/%E3%80%90imagemagick%E3%80%91%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%92%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/), [画像の結合１（重ね合わせ）](https://imagemagick.biz/archives/672)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-composite` で重ね合わせて、`-geometry` でテキストの位置を調整します。

```bash
convert originImg.jpg -font hogeFont.otf -background none -gravity center -size 500x \
 \( -pointsize 50 -fill white -geometry +0-50 caption:"1番目テキスト" \) \
 -composite \
 \( -pointsize 30 -fill blue  -geometry +0+50 caption:"2番目テキスト。とても長いテキストです。" \) \
 -composite output.jpg
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。-geometry オプションは、テキストのオフセットxy位置も指定できるのですね。画像しか指定できないのかと思っていました…